# How did Hyun-su and Yi-kyung's fight end?

Tags: sweet-home

Near the end of the second season of *Sweet Home*, Yi-kyung's daughter decides to attempt to save her life by turning her into a monster. While still struggling to resist the transformation, she fights Hyun-Su, who gets the better of her and pins her down. We then flash to what Hyun-su can see in her mind, then back to Hyun-su (some time later?), with her not around. Hyun-su then comments in voiceover that most monsters are happy inside their illusions, but she would not be.

This seems a little unclear. What happened to Yi-kyung? Did she run away (as a partial or full monster)? Did Hyun-su somehow kill her? Did she just kind of...evaporate, the way that Jun-il exploded instead of becoming a full monster?